# Using JQuery, how do I reference the first-option of a sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have sibling SELECT menu elements like so ...

```
<select name="country1" class="country">...</select>
<select name="state1" class="state">...</select>
```

The names will change (e.g. "country1" ... "countryn"), but the classes associated with the elements (e.g. "country" and "state") will not.  In my Javascript, I want to rewrite this line ...

```
var firstOption = $("#state option:first-child");
```

given that I have a country element, $(countryElt), and I want to say, store the first option of the sibling ".state" element of the $(countryElt).  How do I write that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.state option:first')
  .parent()
  .siblings('.country')
  .find('option:first');
```

HI Dave, per your comments, we had better add a ID in the second select, which is as follows.

```
<select name="state1" class="state" id="state">...</select>.
```

So the code will be changed to

```
$('#state option:first')
  .parent()
  .siblings('.country')
  .find('option:first');
```

Comment: Best to explain clearly how this is the correct answer - as it is, it's hard to determine why this is the correct solution.

Comment: THe problem with this is ".state" matches multiople elements.  I'm interested in the single element that appears next to the $(countryElt).

Comment: Hi, I have multiople elements with ".country" and ".state" designations, so the ids per each would need to be unique.  Because I have multiple country and sttae elements, I was tryign to find a selector that accessed the sibling state element relative to a known country element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent()` and `siblings()`, like this:

```
var stateFirstOption = $("#state option:first");
var countryFirstOption = $stateFirstOption.parent().siblings('.country').find('option:first');
```

Comment: Hi, What I'm tryhing to do is replace the expresison "#state" with a similar expression that uses the $(countryElt) and references the ".state" sibling next to it.  There is no longer an element with id="state".

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(countryElt).next("select.state option:first")
```

Comment: Probably best to explain *why* ;)

Comment: FOr some reason this isn't working.  My <select class="country"> elements are directly next to my <select class="state"> elements.